# How can I create a Rails 3 route that will match all requests and direct to one resource / page?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a rails app (Rails 3.0) that I need to temporarily take out of service. While this is in effect, I want to create a new route that will direct all requests to a single piece of static content. I have a controller set up to serve my static pages.

I tried something like this:

```
match '*' => 'content#holding'
```

and

```
match '*/*' => 'content#holding'
```

to match a wildcard route as described here:[Rails 3 route globbing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) without success.

This is probably a really simple answer, but I couldn't figure it out.

/*EDIT*/
Forgot to mention that I did have this rule at the very top of my routes.rb file.

Comment: Did you put this route at the very top of your routes file?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Rails needs to bind the url parameters to a variable, try this:

```
match '*foo' => 'content#holding'
```

If you also want to match `/`, use parenthesis to specify that `foo` is optional:

```
match '(*foo)' => 'content#holding'
```

Comment: This seems to work for all paths, but not for the root itself. I added an additional temporary root route to the top of routes.rb as well, so now it is working how I want - thanks!

Comment: My end result looks like this: "match '*foo' => redirect('/') #NEWLINE root :to => 'content#holding'" Basically I took your idea, added the redirect, then routed root temporarily to my holding page.

Comment: if you're redirecting, make sure it's a 302 (moved temporarily) rather than a 301 (moved permanently)

Comment: It's working like a charm. But can you share in which place the official document show these information?

Comment: I'd suggest using `all` as a more descriptive variable name.

Answer (score 2):

I did this just yesterday and first came up with the solution that klochner shows.
What I didn't like about this is the fact that whatever you enter in the URL, stays there after the page loads, and since I wanted a catch all route that redirects to my root_url, that wasn't very appealing.

What I came up with looks like this:

```
# in routes.rb
get '*ignore_me' => 'site#unknown_url'

# in SiteController
def unknown_url
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Remember to stick the routes entry at the very bottom of the file!

EDIT:
As Nick pointed out, you can also do the redirect directly in the routes file.

Comment: Yes - I noticed that too. You can also do redirects right in the routes.rb - see my comment above on klochner's answer

Comment: @Nick Ah, now that's nifty. Will switch to that solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something like this where I had domain names as a parameter in my route:

```
match '/:domain_name/', :to => 'sitedetails#index', :domain_name => /.*/, :as =>'sitedetails'
```

The key piece to this was the /.*/ which was a wildcard for pretty much anything.  So maybe you could do something like:

```
match '/:path/', :to => 'content#holding', :path=> /.*/, :as =>'whatever_you_want'
```

Answer (score 0):

Where in "routes.rb" is this line located?

To have priority over other routes, it has to be placed first.

As an alternative, you can look into this: http://onehub.com/blog/posts/rails-maintenance-pages-done-right/

Or this: [Rails: admin-only maintenance mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674298/rails-admin-only-maintenance-mode)

Comment: Oops - forgot to mention that yes, it was on the top of the file.

Comment: Did you restart the server? :-)